# How to read row values on gridview click event and pass them to another fragment

Tags: android, gridview

I have a grid view with 3 columns in it in Fragment A.  I want to read the first column value on a click event and pass the value to FragmentB.

How can I read the fisrst column of the the row clicked on the gridview?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flight, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());
    grid.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            String place= (String) grid.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //How to read the first column value of the row clicked?
        }

    });

    return view;

}
```

grid_row.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Destination"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_flight.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.test.FlightFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"

   />
```

After adding the code

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            if (position==0||position%3==0)
            {
              String place= (String) grid.getItemAtPosition(position);
              interfaceDataCommunicator.SendMarkerPlaceInfo(place);
            }

        }
```

I am having the error

> ```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.FlightFragment cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>             at com.test.FlightFragment.onItemClick(BurnScheduleFragment.java:51)
>             at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
>             at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1539)
>             at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3332)
>             at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4554)
>             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
> ```

AdapterClass

```
 class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Schedule> list;
    private Context context;

    MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        list = new ArrayList();
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        String[] tempDestination = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Destination);
        String[] tempDate = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Date);
        String[] tempDescription = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Description);
        for(int count=0;count<4;count++ ){
            Flight tempFlight = new Flight(tempDestination[count],tempDate[count],tempDescription[count]);
            list.add(tempFlight);
        }
    }
```

View getView method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Schedule tempFlight = list.get(position);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.Destination = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Destination);
            holder.Description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.Time =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Date);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.Destination.setText(tempFlight.Destination);
        holder.Description.setText(tempFlight.Description);
        holder.Time.setText(tempFlight.Time);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: what is in your adapter? post adapter code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 
TextView textViewItem = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Destination)); gave me the expected result. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to read the first column only and your grid contains 3 columns 
i.e.

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
...
```

You will observe, the first column will only have either index '0' or multiple of 3.

In your method `OnClickListener` you can check the value of **int position.**

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            //How to read the first column value of the row clicked?
             if (position==0||position%3==0)
             {
              // Do whatever you want here
              String place= tempDestination[count];

             }

        }

    });
```

Comment: what is tempDestination[count];?

Comment: @user4657208 Check your code in the constructor of MyAdapter. Its your destination array.

Answer (score 0):

In MyAdapter class:

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
   String str = "some text";
    convertView.setTag(str);//you can pass any object in place of string

    return convertView;
}
```

now catch the value in your activity like below:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
     String = view.getTag();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong

First you have to get the view(It should be textview in your case) , then get the

value from this textview

E.g.

```
String contactId = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourtextviewid)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: It is giving the error unexpected cast to textview, layout tag was gridview